# Timeout expired while running INSERT INTO SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I want to insert data using SQL INSERT INTO statement, but an error Timeout expired occur. Anybody can help me. Thanxs. The code are like this.

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IMS"].ConnectionString);                
            SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand();
            sqlCom = sqlConn.CreateCommand();                

            var strField = new List<string>();
            var strVal = new List<string>();                

            if (this.Row.TriggerEntityID != null)
            {
                sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntityId", this.Row.TriggerEntityID);
                strField.Add("EntityID");
                strVal.Add("@EntityId");
            }

            if (this.Row.TriggerProjectID != null)
            {
                sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", this.Row.TriggerProjectID);
                strField.Add("ProjectID");
                strVal.Add("@ProjectId");
            }

            sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EngagementId", this.Row.Id);

            string[] arrField = strField.ToArray();
            string[] arrVal = strVal.ToArray();

            string fld = arrField[0];
            string val = arrVal[0];
            for (var j = 1; j < arrField.Length; j++)
            {
                fld = fld + "," + arrField[j];
                val = val + "," + arrVal[j];
            }                

            sqlCom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Engagement_Project_Entity (EngagementID, " + fld + ") VALUES (@EngagementId, " + val + ")";

            sqlConn.Open();
            sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConn.Close();
```

Am I missing something? or the sequence is wrong?

Comment: You should tag with the language you are using (e.g. .NET).  This sounds like there is a problem with the database connection.

Comment: thanxs for the suggestion..

Comment: Is the error triggered during open or execute?  How long before the time out error triggered?

Comment: the error triggered during execute.. in 30sec ++, then the error triggered..

Comment: I would verify that the database isn't corrupted.  Try using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which comes with SQL Studion.  I would try performing same Insert command and see if you get any errors.  If the value is already in the database you should be using an UPDATE instead of an INSERT.

Comment: i have try before this and it's works.. maybe the sequence for Open(), ExecuteNonQuery() and Close() might be problem?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: tqvm for ur advice..

Answer (score 1):

If you got a timeout exception during a query execution, that clearly shows that your C# code managed to pass the query over to the database and the database tried executing the query, but it couldn't complete the execution before the timeout.

So here are few troubleshooting steps I would take.

1. First make sure the timeout you are getting is an execution timeout
   and not a connection timeout. If it is connection timeout, that means the SQL Server is not accessible at the moment. If it is a query execution timeout, follow the below steps to find out exactly what is causing the query to timeout.
2. Use SQL Server Profiler (From Tools menu in SQL Server Management Studio) to find out the exact query that is getting fired when this piece of code executes.
3. Check if too many fld and value pairs are generated by the code.
4. Try executing the same query from SQL Server Management Studio and find out if the timeout is reproducible. If you get the same problem from SQL Server
   Management Studio as well, fix the query.

Comment: Just go to Tools menu from SQL Server Management Studio. Use the option SQL Server Profiler. Accept the defaults and start a trace. Observe the trace window where queries start appearing. When you execute the C# code, you should see your query in the trace.